# What is the reciprocal of an infinitesimal?

Tags: infinity, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

"An infinitesimal is some quantity that is explicitly nonzero and yet smaller in absolute value than any real quantity." (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Infinitesimal.html)

What is the reciprocal of an infinitesimal?

After reading some comments, I see a challenging juxtaposition of (1) and (2):

(1) The reciprocal of any positive real number greater than zero is a finite number.

(2) The reciprocal of any positive number less than any real positive number is greater than any real number.

And I will consider alternative definitions of "infinitesimals."

Comment: An infinite number.

Comment: If infinitesimals exist, then their reciprocals will obviously be numbers greater than any real number (if positive) or smaller than any real number (if negative). If they don't, then ... well, there is nothing to talk about. The set of real numbers does not have infinitesimals but [can be extended to contain (some implementation of) them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number), and then you end up with the situation as in my first sentence.

Comment: Also, if you start from a perspective that the numbers are "out there" and we are discovering them, and then the infinitesimals either objectively exist or they not, what do you even make of my previous comment? - i.e., of the fact that mathematicians have two competing models of real numbers, which both work perfectly, and one has infinitesimals (and infinite numbers), and the other doesn't, and not only they can coexist peacefully, but there are strong links between them ("[Transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle)")...

Comment: The math world comment is not an actual definition of infinitesimal. You could use a precise model of the hyper reals but these can be complicated to establish

Comment: @FShrike If you're correct in that the MathWorld definition is incorrect, can you define "infinitesimals" in a single paragraph?

Comment: No, "infinitesmals" cannot be defined in a single paragraph.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you are interested in how "infinitesimals" are *actually* defined, a much better starting place would be a discussion of *nonstandard analysis*; [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis#Approaches_to_nonstandard_analysis) does an okay job in that regard.

Comment: @JamesGoetz I’m not saying the mathworld definition is incorrect, I’m saying (without a *lot* of contextual definitions) it’s just not a definition, rather an intuitive description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the inverse of an infinitesimal give an infinite number?  That depends on what you mean by "infinite number".  The term is used in many different senses in mathematics.  For the purpose of doing calculus, it is helpful to use a more specific term that is also commonly found in the literature: "unlimited".  An infinitesimal is smaller in absolute value than every positive standard real number, and an unlimited number (the inverse of an infinitesimal) is greater in absolute value than every standard real number.

Abraham Robinson was the first to pioneer a usable approach to infinitesimal analysis based on infinitesimals in the 1960s.  His approach could be described as a model-theoretic one, and involves extending the real numbers $\mathbb R$ to an ordered field of hyperreals ${}^\ast\mathbb R$.

About a decade later, an alternative approach to analysis with infinitesimals was developed  by Hrbacek and Nelson that could be called an axiomatic approach.  Here the usual language of set theory based on the membership relation $\in$ is extended to a richer language incorporating a new one-place relation, or predicate, "standard", together with axioms governing the interaction of the new predicate with the usual Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms.  Here it is important to keep in mind that the "axiomatic approach" does not amount to a brave new world of axioms beyond Zermelo-Fraenkel; Hrbacek and Nelson proved conservativity results that show that the new systems are conservative over ZFC.  Here one defines $\mathbb N$, as usual, as the smallest inductive set; $\mathbb Z$ by adding negatives; $\mathbb Q$ as its field of fractions; and the real line $\mathbb R$ as the set of Dedekind cuts on $\mathbb Q$.

In the axiomatic approach, one finds infinitesimals and unlimited numbers within the real line itself (rather than an extension thereof).  The definitions are exactly the ones given above.

Then infinitesimals can be defined in a single sentence.

I add a historical note based on an exchange of *comments*.  The following is a summary of [our recent publication](https://doi.org/10.14708/am.v16i1.7169).  Leibniz had a distinction between assignable and inassignable numbers, which was only properly understood with Robinson's theory when it was formalized as the distinction between standard and nonstandard numbers.  As late as the middle of the 19th century, infinitesimals were still in routine use by the greats such as Cauchy, Poisson, and Coriolis.  The rigorisation of analysis achieved in the next generation of mathematicians was of course a great accomplishment, but in one significant way it was also a failure.  Namely, the formalisation of the foundations that was eventually developed failed to include a formalisation of infinitesimals, which until then were the bread and butter of analysis.  At any rate, the ZFC foundations were specifically designed to exclude infinitesimals, which were routinely considered contradictory.  It is to be noted that mathematical validity is not measured by how "new" a theory is.  The axiomatic foundations for infinitesimal analysis are a more faithful formalisation of analysis than those provided by the traditional non-infinitesimal axiomatisations.  Recently we developed an axiomatisation whose three additional axioms correspond to three principles already found in Leibniz; see [this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2021.102959).  They are no more elaborate than the traditional foundations.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. And I imagine that you assume that "reciprocal" and "inverse" are synonymous in this case. Is that correct?

Comment: @JamesGoetz, yes.